# convert scala string to RDD[seq[string]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
 // 4 workers
  val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]", "naivebayes")

  // Load documents (one per line).
  val documents: RDD[Seq[String]] = sc.textFile("/tmp/test.txt").map(_.split(" ").toSeq)

  documents.zipWithIndex.foreach{
  case (e, i) =>
  val collectedResult = Tokenizer.tokenize(e.mkString)
  }

  val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  //pass collectedResult instead of document
  val tf: RDD[Vector] = hashingTF.transform(documents)

  tf.cache()
  val idf = new IDF().fit(tf)
  val tfidf: RDD[Vector] = idf.transform(tf)
```

in the above code snippet, i would want to extract collectedResult to reuse it for hashingTF.transform, How can this be achieved where the signature of tokenize function is

```
 def tokenize(content: String): Seq[String] = {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want `map` rather than `foreach`. I don't understand what you're using `zipWithIndex` for, nor why you're calling `split` on your lines only to join them straight back up again with `mkString`.

```
val lines: Rdd[String] = sc.textFile("/tmp/test.txt")
val tokenizedLines = lines.map(tokenize)
val hashes = tokenizedLines.map(hashingTF)
hashes.cache()
...
```

Comment: @Imm how do i declare an other rdd? sorry i am a newbie!

Comment: You said you wanted to append the return value of that function to some other `RDD[Seq[String]]`, no? `otherRdd` is the one you want to append to.

Comment: inp.zipWithIndex.foreach{
  case (e, i) =>
  val result: RDD[Seq[String]] ++ = sc.parallelize(Seq(Tokenizer.tokenize(e)))
  }
i guess this is wrong, i wanted to declare the result out of loop, append it and get as one rdd. i am not sure on how i can do this.

Comment: I think you should step back a bit, and ask a question about what you actually want to achieve. What do you have, and what do you want to end up with? Thinking in terms of "appending" is probably not what you want if your goal is to create a parallel collection.

Comment: @Imm i have edited my question with the code snippet, all i intend is to run a test program to print the values of tfidf.